# Run macro for candidates in a list

Tags: excel, vba, list

I have a macro, named MACRO1, for calculations and pasting results to another worksheet.

Every time I have to enter the name of candidates (PETER, JOHN, MARY, KATIE, etc) to cell B1 of my worksheet, named MAINSHEET, to update values in a range before I run MACRO1.

The list of candidates was being put onto A1:A500 of MAINSHEET (i.e. I have to run MACRO1 for 500 hundred times).

I am looking for a code to automate the step of "entering value of A1 to B1, run MACRO1, entering value of A2 to B1, run MACRO1, entering value of A3 to B1, run MACRO1..."

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Use a loop. Hard to be more specific when you haven't shown your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or if you don't want to modify your Macro, have another one run it in a loop for you:

```
Sub loops()
Dim i As Long, ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Worksheets("MAINSHEET")
For i = 1 To 500
    ws.Range("B1") = ws.Range("A" & i)
    Call MACRO1
Next i
End Sub
```